# What is the fastest way in a growing table to know if at least one line is existing with two search (WHERE) criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In pgsql, what's the fastest request to see if a table `BLOG_POST` is having column `company_id=5` and `status_id=3` at least once considering the table can grow?

I have many company using that table and they can have many entry, my end goal is too create a method named `hasCompanyAlreadyPublishedABlogPost(companyId)`.

Comment: Have you try to add an index?(If these columns are not primary key) Could you have priviledge with the database to add and index?

Comment: Yes I have added an index and we can have more than one result for a same company_id with status_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `EXISTS` condition would do:

```
select exists (select * 
               from blog_post
               where company_id = 5
                 and status_id = 3);
```

Obviously you want an index on `blog_post(company_id, status_id)`

Comment: What if many company post also in this table and if the table grow a day to a hundred of thousand of lines or even more ? Will this still be fast enough ?

Comment: With the suggested index, yes. ("hundreds of thousands" of rows is considered small these days)

Comment: What is considering big? When this will hit the limit I am worried about ?

Comment: Hundreds of millions. But with the suggested index, probably more like billions

Answer (score 0):

To further improve the performance we can do this:

```
select exists (select id
               from blog_post
               where company_id = 5
                 and status_id = 3 limit 1);
```

1. Add limit in nested query
2. Instead of select * we can do select any_column

I have tried this with a sample database:

with id and limit:

```
explain analyze (select exists (select user_id from sample_table where sample_ids=4 and user_id=5 limit 1));
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=8.17..8.18 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using sample_table_pkey on sample_table  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (user_id = 5)
           Filter: (sample_ids = 4)
 Planning Time: 0.091 ms
 Execution Time: 0.032 ms
```

without id and *

```
explain analyze (select exists (select * from sample_table where sample_ids=4 and user_id=5));
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=8.17..8.18 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using sample_table_pkey on sample_table  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (user_id = 5)
           Filter: (sample_ids = 4)
 Planning Time: 0.084 ms
 Execution Time: 0.034 ms
```